# How can I re-use the TinyMCE functionality for bold/italic/strikethrough for my custom buttons?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I'm just looking to add a few buttons to the TinyMCE editor via a plugin. The buttons will have the exact same functionality as the bold/italic/strikethrough buttons, but will instead be for the HTML tags: `<mark>` and `<ins>`.

Can I re-use the code for these existing buttons and somehow extend it to change the html tag that is inserted?

I dug through the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce) and could not find where this functionality is written. I'm hoping there is a simple API I can extend.

I found some [command identifiers](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/TinyMCE3x@Command_identifiers/) that look promising, like `mceInsertContent` that can insert something simple like an `<hr />`, but nothing for inserting tags around the selected text.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a simple toolbar button to wrap selected text with additional information by adding a small bit of code to your TinyMCE configuration.

**Step 1:  Define the custom button**

The first thing you need to do is create a custom button (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/toolbarbuttons/).  The code would look something like this:

```
editor.ui.registry.addButton('wrapselection', {
    text: 'Wrap Selection',
    onAction: function () {
        editor.insertContent("<mark>" + editor.selection.getContent() + "</mark>");
    }
});
```

You add this in the `setup()` function in your TinyMCE configuration.

**Step 2:  Add the button to the toolbar**

Your TinyMCE configuration has a `toolbar` setting that controls what buttons appear on the toolbar.  You need to add your new custom button to the toolbar:

```
toolbar: "wrapselection | code undo redo | bold italic | bullist numlist"
```

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows all of this in action: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/lQgaab/2

Comment: So I know that I could just as easily do the opposite to remove the tag if the text is highlighted and clicked again, but what if only a portion of the text inside the tag is selected. For example, if the HTML in the editor is: <mark>I want to unmark the word "this"</mark> ... and I highlight "this" and click the button, it should remove that word from the html tag, similar to how the "bold" button works.